# How to use foreach loop in order to get whole block of information related to criteria: "is greater than"?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to use FOREACH loop in order to get whole block of information  related to criteria: "is greater than" the number posted by user (in this case $metsq=$_POST['metersq'];)
For example, in code I posted, if user write **90**, it should outputs only
color - blue
msq - 100
city - Prague

I tried this code, but, obviously, I don't have much experience. 
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $houses = array(
        'house1'=>array(
        'color'=>'green',
        'msq'=>100,
        'city'=>'Prague'
    ),

        'house2'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'msq'=>30,
        'city'=>'Belgrade'
    ),
        'house3'=>array(
        'color'=>'blue',
        'msq'=>50,
        'city'=>'London'
    ),
        'house4'=>array(
        'color'=>'blue',
        'msq'=>50,
        'city'=>'Belgrade'
    )
);

$col=$_POST['colors'];
$metsq=$_POST['metersq'];
$cit=$_POST['cities'];

foreach($houses as $house=>$data) {
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        if($value>=$metsq) {
            echo "$key - $value </br>";
        }
    } 
} else {
    echo "Go, search";
}
?>


<form action="?" method="post">
<select name="colors" >

<option>green</option></br>
<option>blue</option></br>
<option>red</option></br>
</select>

<input type="number" name="metersq" id="metersq" maxlength="3" />m2</br>

<select name="cities">

<option>Prague</option></br>
<option>Belgrade</option></br>
<option>London</option></br>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Find" name="button"id="button" />
```

Comment: How do you associate 90 with the first array? it sounds like an if statement with the `>= -- == -- =<` operators is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to output the entire `house1` as a set of key/value pairs.

You're pretty close:

```
foreach($houses as $house=>$data){
    if( $data['msq'] >= $metsq ) {
        foreach( $data as $key=>$value ) {
            echo "$key - $value <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem you were having is that you were really only outputting data when the specific key met your conditional. But you were making comparisions like `blue >= 90` which could have unexpected results.

Comment: @natttan You're welcome. And don't forget to accept an answer if your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the house data, just loop through the 'msq' keys:

```
foreach($houses as $house){
    if($house['msq']>=intval($metsq)){
        echo "msq - {$house['msq']} </br>";
    }
}
```

Also, you might need to make sure that they are integers, with [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Comment: Just a note, `$key` and `$value` are not defined in your sample.

Comment: That'll also throw a parse error, since you're trying to call an array key value inside a scalar value. I've updated your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested foreach loops. You just need to compare the `msq` key in each house element of the array like this:

```
foreach($houses as $house=>$data){
    if ($data['msq'] >= $metsq) {
        // found a matching house so do something with it
        var_dump($house, $data);
    }
}
```